# Telugu fonts (telugu conjuncts) not working properly in Android 2.2

Tags: java, android, localization, rendering

I am trying to display telugu fonts in my app.
Code

```
Typeface Telugu;
Telugu = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/withG.ttf");
TextView tt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.label);
tt.setTypeface(Telugu);
tt.setText("Some telugu text");
```

This works fine in Android 4.2. But when run the app in Android 2.2, conjuncts are not rendered properly.

Guys anybody knows what to do?

Answer (score 1):

The old version of android had very few language support.. like version 2.2 had only 26 languages support, which they doubled in 2.3 and further increased with more upcomming versions.

http://www.talkandroid.com/22956-android-2-3-gingerbread-doubles-language-support-from-2-2-froyo/

It is because of the lack of support in 2.2 it is not rendered properly.

Comment: Then some android manufacturers are able to display it in 2.2. What custom changes I need to make to support that.

Comment: @nucleons may be some third party jar is doing the trick there, anyways don't worry much on version 2.2 it is used by only 4% people of all android users. You can take a look at the latest report http://www.androidauthority.com/jelly-bean-market-share-rising-183444/